# Why do I get free variable warnings with use-package?

Tags: use-package

I have, for instance, this in my `.emacs`:

```
(use-package company
  :bind (("M-RET" . company-complete))
  :demand                               ; load it now (better for eglot)
  :config
  (global-company-mode)
  (setq company-backends '(company-capf company-semantic company-dabbrev-code
                                        company-dabbrev company-etags
                                        company-keywords))
  (setq company-dabbrev-downcase nil ; make case-sensitive
    company-dabbrev-ignore-case nil) ; make case-sensitive
)
```

The last setq gives flycheck free-variable warnings for `company-dabbrev-downcase` and `company-dabbrev-ignore-case` even though they are both defined with `defcustom` in `company-mode`. Should I just ignore these warnings, or should I do something differently to fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [the :defines keyword](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#byte-compiling-your-emacs) in `use-package`. According to `use-package`'s README it's for "introduce[ing] dummy variable and function declarations solely for the sake of the byte-compiler".

```
(use-package company
  :defines company-dabbrev-downcase company-dabbrev-ignore-case
  ...)
```